# Sorting a multi-dimensional array by the size of its sub-arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array of arrays, and I want to sort the big array by the # of indexes in the sub-arrays, what would be the most efficient way to do that?

This is what I have so far

```
$sortorder = array_map('count', $largearray);
array_multisort($sortorder, $largearray);
```

Anything better than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
usort($array, create_function('$a, $b', 'return bccomp(count($a), count($b));'));
```

Comment: Thanks, one other thing-- is there a way to update this to make it ignore indexes without values when counting?