# Sort a PHP associative array alphabeticlly and by size

Tags: php, sorting

I have a multidiemensional associatve array that I am trying to sort both alphabetically and by size. Check the example that im currently getting but now I want to sort the Keys "ACC, ABB, AAB" alphabetically without editing the size sorting if that makes sense.

```
arsort($myarray);

// Returns an array sorted by its value size from biggest to smallest but need to to also sort it keys alpabetically without amongest keys that have the same size.

$myArray = Array (     <--- Arrange this alphabetically and by size
        [AAA] => Array ( is 1st
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1 
            [4] => 1
        )      
        [ACC] => Array ( should be 3rd
            [1] => 1 
            [2] => 1 
        )      
        [ABB] => Array ( should be 2nd
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1 
        )      
        [AAB] => Array ( should be 1st
            [1] => 1 
            [2] => 1 
        )      
        [AA] => Array ( is 1st
            [1] => 1 
        )      
        [AB] => Array ( is 2nd
            [1] => 1 
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: go thru this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151155/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-the-size-of-its-sub-arrays for sorting by size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just made a loop do to what I wanted was more than just a built-in function. Hope its understandable I'm pretty bad at explaining code  :S

```
arsort($myArray);                                     // Sorts array by size
reset($myArray);
$first_key = key($myArray);
$count = count($myArray[$first_key], COUNT_RECURSIVE); // Get the largest value in array

$temp_array = array();
$sorted_array = array();
for($i = $count; $i >= 1; $i--){                      // Loops from the largest value to the smallest to create temp array for each size
    foreach($myArray as $name => $values){            // Loops Through $myArray
        if(count($myArray [$name]) == $i){            // Checks each Key in $myArray to see if size is the same as $I
            $temp_array[$name] = $myArray[$name];     // Adds to $temp_array
        }

    }
    ksort($temp_array);                               // Sorts temp array created in loop above alpahbetically
    $sorted_array += $temp_array;                     // and adds its to a new array
    $temp_array = array();
}
```

This loops allows you to sort by size of array values and then if there are multiple keys with the same value is will sort those alphabetically

```
$myArray = Array (    // This array sorted by size only - arsort($myArray)
    [AB] => Array (
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1 
    )      
    [AA] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1 
    )
    [AC] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1 
    )      
    [BB] => Array (
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1 
    )      
    [BA] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 1 
    )      
    [CA] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
    )      
    [CB] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
    ) 
)

$myArray = Array (     // Array Sorted By Size and Alphabetically - After loop
    [AA] => Array (
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1 
    )      
    [AB] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1 
    ) 
    [AC] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1 
    )      
    [BA] => Array (
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1 
    )      
    [BB] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 1 
    )      
    [CA] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
    )      
    [CB] => Array (
        [1] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use key sorting to sort your array. As per your requirement you want to sort array based on keys
This wil work for you...

```
ksort($myArray);
```

And what do you mean by sorting by size ?? I did nt get 2nd part of ur question

Comment: Oh basically when i mean size i mean the size of the array the key is holding Key [AAA] hold an array of 4.